# I want to create a program with Automator and youtube-dl

Tags: automator, google-chrome, youtube

I want to create an app with Automator on macOS Sierra (MacBook Pro 2012) which fetches the URLs of all pages opened in Google Chrome and add them to a function that I've  created based on youtube-dl.

The function named go:

```
function go {
    youtube-dl "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9" "$10" "$11" "$12" "$13" "$14" "$15" "$16" "$17"
}
```

The URLs of the pages should replace the variables $1 $2 .....

Comment: Just copying the URL text and replacing the variables. automatically

Comment: You need to provide more and better details on how you expect this to work! Are you targeting specific videos or every video link on a given page, etc.? Please provide a real world example, and edit it into your OP.

Comment: @ user3439894 I just want to open some videos on chrome and run the automator which will copy the opened video urls instead of the variables in the fonction go. it's too simple to understand my freind.

Comment: I've update my answer again. :)

Answer (score 2):

The **AppleScript** example *code*, shown below, does the following:

- If Google Chrome is running, creates a *list* of every *tab* of every *window*.
- Looks for "YouTube" in the *title* of every *tab* of every *window* in the *list*.
- If the *title* of a *tab* contains "YouTube", it adds the *URL* of that *tab* to a *list* of *URLs*.
- If the *list* of *URLs* is not empty, it changes directory to the Downloads folder and then downloads the video of each *URL* in the *list* of *URLs*, one at a time.
- If the *list* of *URLs* is not empty, it displays a *notification* when the downloading starts, and again when finished.

---

```
on run
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        if running then
            set theseURLs to {}
            set theSearchString to "YouTube"
            set theWindowList to every window
            repeat with thisWindow in theWindowList
                set theTabList to every tab of thisWindow
                repeat with thisTab in theTabList
                    if theSearchString is in (title of thisTab as string) then
                        set end of theseURLs to (URL of thisTab as string)
                    end if
                end repeat
            end repeat
        else
            tell current application
                display notification "Google Chrome is not open!"
                return
            end tell
        end if
    end tell
    tell current application
        if theseURLs is not {} then
            display notification "Downloading YouTube Video..."
            repeat with thisURL in theseURLs
                do shell script "cd \"$HOME/Downloads\"; ./youtube-dl -q --no-warnings " & quoted form of thisURL
            end repeat
            display notification "YouTube Video Downloading Finished."
        end if
    end tell
end run
```

This **AppleScript** *code* can be used in an **AppleScript** *application* or a **Run AppleScript** *action* in an **Automator** *application*.

**Note:** The above example *code* does not employ all possible forms of *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways how to achieve an objective such as downloading a **YouTube** video from each **YouTube** *tab* in **Google Chrome** using `youtube-dl`. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted. This would include using `try` *statements* and `on error` *handlers* as/where appropriate. Although, as presently coded, it should run okay without that level of *error handling*.

If this example *code* is not acceptable in lieu of your *go function*, then you can modify the *code* as needed/wanted to accomplish the end goal of downloading every **YouTube** video of every *tab* of every *window* in **Google Chrome** that has "YouTube" in the *title* (*which this code already does*).

The `PATH` passed to a `do shell script` *command* is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, and if `youtube-dl` is not in that `PATH`, then include the *fully qualified pathname* to the *executable*. As coded in the example *code*, I have it in my **Downloads** folder and because I first *change directory* to there, all I needed to do is preface it with: `./`

Also as coded, because it's searching the *title* of each *tab* for "YouTube", if the **URL** is not in the form of, e.g. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=`, it will download all videos on that **YouTube** page. In other words, if it's in the form of e.g. `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=`, then it going to do lots of downloading from that page.

If that's an issue, then change the following lines of *code* as shown:

- Change: `set theSearchString to "YouTube"`
- To: `set theSearchString to "youtube.com/watch"`
- Change: `if theSearchString is in (title of thisTab as string) then`
- To: `if theSearchString is in (URL of thisTab as string) then`

Then only the *URLs* in that form of the **URL** are added to the *list* of *URLs* to be downloaded.